# Mysql Preg Replace command

Tags: mysql, wordpress

thanks for reading.

I have this record for my wordpress media which is of the following text

```
"wp-content/uploads/2015/03/file.jpg" and many other files e.g
"wp-content/uploads/2015/03/somestuffs.mp4"
```

I wanna do a mass update on the return record by replacing

```
2015/03 with 2014/09
```

How do I achieve this with update statement

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a literal search and replace, you don't need regex matching, just a simple replace.

`UPDATE wp_table SET file = REPLACE(file, 'uploads/2015/03', 'uploads/2014/09');`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using `mysql` default `replace` function to mass replacement, but you can also use `wordpress`  search & replace plugin for it that will be a better or easy choice.

```
UPDATE wp_table_name SET field = replace(field,'2015/03','2014/09');

UPDATE table_name SET field = replace(field,'[string-to-find]','[string-that-will-replace-it]');
```

See [MYSQL REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

See [WORDPRESS SEARCH & REPLACE](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)

**NB:** But Before you do that, you should definitely do a database dump or whatever you use for backups.